# trying to change background color of rows in a datagrid based on multicell values

Tags: c#, wpf

I need help binding this WPF to multiple datatriggers. I need to change row color based on two values not just the one. I wasn't able to figure out how to do that

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AgentState}" Value="AUX-IN">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
 </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: okay.... so what do you need from stackoverflow?

Comment: You'd be better off doing it in XAML with row and cell styles.

Comment: @ ed plunkett I know how to change individual cells based on value in XAML but I don't know how to edit a whole row.

Comment: Maybe with a row style? What did you try? Where did you run into trouble?

Comment: *"I'm having issues accessing my DataGrid as an object"* -- Troubles? Are you able to provide any hints, however coy, about the exact nature of these troubles? Or is it more of an indefinable sense of unease that you can't quite put your finger on? You're not just complaining about life to your cellmate here, you're asking professionals for concrete help with specifics.

Comment: so I added the XAML I've tried but i'm not very firmiliar with setting triggers for data in each cell. that would be perfect if I could figure out how to set a trigger for row contains a cell set at AUX-IN and another cell in the same row contains General. I've also removed un-needed code

Comment: @Ed Plunkett I changed the entire question for what I need to make more sense. Sorry for the confusion and uselessness of previous information.

Comment: *"I need to change row color based on two values not just the one"*: Did you have a particular scenario in mind? Maybe green if `Foo` and `Bar` are `true`, or yellow if `Baz == "Fred" && Planxty <= 6`? XAML triggers are very good at doing A if B equals C. For more complicated scenarios you can write converters.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out.  I didn't know multidatatrigger existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                       <Style.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding AgentState}" Value="ACD-IN"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding AuxReasons}" Value="General"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>

                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```